# Wrong spacing in margin notes for equations and SI units

Tags: math-mode, spacing, margins, sidenotes, eulervm

I am trying to use the [**mnote**](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnotes/mnotes.pdf) package to write margin notes that I can conveniently hide with a single command (package option). Unfortunately, the notes have very odd (and wrong?) spacing when it comes to mathematical formulae and quantities with units (from the **siunitx** package).

Here is a MWE showcasing the issues:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[mnwidth=\marginparwidth,
sidenotes]{mnotes}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

This paragraph is a test for the \texttt{mnote} package,\MNOTE{This is a note. Formulae displayed with \texttt{mnote} look rather odd: \[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).\] The spacing looks off in formulae such as $E=mc^2$ as well as numbers \SI{10}{\angstrom}.} which does not seem to play well with mathematical formulae:
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).
\]
$E = mc^2$ is an equation with the expected spacing. \textit{$E = mc^2$ is an equation within italic text}. \SI{10}{\angstrom} also has the expected spacing.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

**Is there a way to get the correct spacing (the same as in the main text) in margin notes created with [**mnote**](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnotes/mnotes.pdf)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `mnote` other than the fact that it uses `\tiny` font size.

The “problem” is in the Euler fonts, that by precise choice use quite wide sidebearings in smaller sizes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).
\]

\tiny
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get a slightly better output with `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  mnwidth=\marginparwidth,
  sidenotes
]{mnotes}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\renewcommand{\MNFONT}{\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

This paragraph is a test for the \texttt{mnote} package,%
\MNOTE{This is a note. Formulae displayed with \texttt{mnote} 
  look rather odd: \[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).\] The 
  spacing looks off in formulae such as $E=mc^2$ as well as numbers \SI{1}{\nano\meter}.}
which does not seem to play well with mathematical formulae:
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).
\]
$E = mc^2$ is an equation with the expected spacing. 
\textit{$E = mc^2$ is an equation within italic text}. \SI{1}{\nano\meter} 
also has the expected spacing.

\end{document}
```

I fixed the `\angstrom` deprecated unit.

[image]

Alternatively, define a suitable math version in which the fonts are scaled from the 10pt size. I also added `mode=text` to `siunitx` in order to get Palatino for units.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
  mnwidth=\marginparwidth,
  sidenotes
]{mnotes}

\usepackage[mode=text]{siunitx}

\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{scaledzeur}{\skewchar \font =127}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{scaledzeur}{m}{n}{<-> zeurm10}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{scaledzeus}{\skewchar \font =176}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{scaledzeus}{m}{n}{<-> zeusm10}{}
\DeclareMathVersion{scaledeuler}{}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{scaledeuler}{U}{scaledzeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{scaledeuler}{U}{scaledzeus}{m}{n}


\renewcommand{\MNFONT}{\tiny\mathversion{scaledeuler}}

\begin{document}

This paragraph is a test for the \texttt{mnote} package,%
\MNOTE{This is a note. Formulae displayed with \texttt{mnote} 
  look rather odd: \[\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).\] The 
  spacing looks off in formulae such as $E=mc^2$ as well as numbers \SI{1}{\nano\meter}.}
which does not seem to play well with mathematical formulae:
\[
    \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a).
\]
$E = mc^2$ is an equation with the expected spacing. 
\textit{$E = mc^2$ is an equation within italic text}. \SI{1}{\nano\meter} 
also has the expected spacing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic and detailed answer!